# Indexing ILIKE ALL for speed on large database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that runs super slow:

```
select *
from food
where name ilike all(string_to_array(replace('%'||'beef pot noodle'||'%',' ','%,%'), ','))

Gather  (cost=1000.00..272754.60 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=494.780..15763.435 rows=84 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on food  (cost=0.00..271754.50 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=275.324..15333.204 rows=28 loops=3)
        Filter: ((name)::text ~~* ALL ('{%beef%,%pot%,%noodle%}'::text[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2585844
Planning Time: 7.949 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 12
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 80.426 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 130.281 ms, Emission 333.119 ms, Total 543.826 ms
Execution Time: 15846.520 ms
```

The table has 10 million rows and looks like:

| id | name | userid | date | calories | units | verified | public | disabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4874759 | Ocean Spray Cran•energy Raspberry | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:08 | 400 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "serving": 10} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874762 | Lindt 99% Cocoa Chocolate | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:09 | 567 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "serving": 100} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874772 | Nutrilett Karamell | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:15 | 361 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "serving": 100} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874776 | Sprouted Khorasan Honey | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:17 | 333.33 | {"lb": 453.6, "ml": 0.2, "oz": 28.3, "cup": 30, "gram": 1, "fl oz": 5.6, "teaspoon": 0.9, "tablespoon": 2.8} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874778 | Sprouted Khorasan Honey O's | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:18 | 331.11 | {"lb": 453.6, "ml": 0.2, "oz": 28.3, "cup": 30, "gram": 1, "fl oz": 5.6, "teaspoon": 0.9, "tablespoon": 2.8} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874780 | Smoked Turkey Sandwich Light Mayo | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:20 | 202.63 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "sandwich": 152.2} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874783 | Vd Coffee with Half and Half | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:22 | 15.56 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "serving": 270} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874796 | Sundried Feta Omelette | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:28 | 90.22 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "omelette": 224.5} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4874803 | Snack - Cornbeef Sandwich | NULL | 2022-03-16 20:13:32 | 246.79 | {"lb": 453.6, "oz": 28.3, "gram": 1, "sandwich": 265} | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

I have used a trgm index on the name column:

```
CREATE INDEX table_gin_trgm_idx ON table USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

And this works well when the query is:

```
select *
from food
where name ilike '%beef pot noodle%'

Bitmap Heap Scan on food  (cost=446.01..1230.71 rows=776 width=144) (actual time=646.761..647.533 rows=3 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~* '%beef pot noodle%'::text)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 72
  Heap Blocks: exact=65
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_food_name  (cost=0.00..445.82 rows=776 width=0) (actual time=644.843..644.843 rows=75 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~* '%beef pot noodle%'::text)
Planning Time: 11.846 ms
Execution Time: 656.579 ms
```

However I return much better results when doing:

```
name ilike all(string_to_array(replace('%'||'beef pot noodle'||'%',' ','%,%')
```

So my question is, how do I best utilise indexes on `ilike all`? My aim is to get the query as fast as possible.

UPDATE: The `all()` wasn't picking up the index. I refactored the query to not use `all()` and it's now much faster.

```
select * from food where name ilike '%beef%' AND name ilike '%pot%' AND name ilike '%noodle%';

Bitmap Heap Scan on food  (cost=423.01..424.03 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=70.240..77.661 rows=84 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((name)::text ~~* '%beef%'::text) AND ((name)::text ~~* '%pot%'::text) AND ((name)::text ~~* '%noodle%'::text))
  Heap Blocks: exact=74
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_food_name  (cost=0.00..423.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=70.196..70.197 rows=84 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((name)::text ~~* '%beef%'::text) AND ((name)::text ~~* '%pot%'::text) AND ((name)::text ~~* '%noodle%'::text))
Planning Time: 0.499 ms
Execution Time: 77.717 ms
```

Comment: There is no way to make this fast. With a single pattern it is possible.

Comment: The issue was the all() not using the index. I refactored the query to not use all() and the index now works. Speed is good. Cheers for the help everyone. (: